# Samsung UE590 4k monitor DisplayPort + Ubuntu 18.04 black screen before log in screen

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, display, hdmi

I have a bit of a weird issue here. Let me know how I can make the description more useful (perhaps some log, not sure which one and how I would give it to you, because the problem is before the log on).

So when I use a display port with on my Samsung UE590 with no HDMI plugged in computer, nor into the monitor, I boot up, I can see the BIOS boot-up screen, then the screen turns purple and Ubuntu starts loading. Then just before the log on screen (it never reaches it), it turns black and the screen shuts off and now we have black screen and that's it. But I can see that the Ubuntu probably loaded because: 1) PC power on LED button is on, 2) my keyboard lights are on. If I restart, same problem.

However, if I employ the following approach I do make it work, but it is a hassle. I first plug in HDMI and DisplayPort cables into my PC. I only plug in the HDMI cable into my monitor. I wait for the purple screen. Now I plug in the Display Port. Everything boots up normally (in HDMI). Then I switch the source to Display Port and voila, it works... But that was a lot of work.

My NVIDIA Driver Version is: 390.87. I believe that by default I have a HDMI monitor switched on in the X Server, and that may be the issue. But I cannot find a way to set the default screen to the DP (DisplayPort). Would be very thankful for the tips. I have been doing this routine for two months now..

Comment: another strange thing is that if I boot into Windows, then there is no problem. I only have this issue with my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: i can confirm similar behaviour - running a gtx1070, except when I switch to DP, gnome disappears and I'm left with the desktop background

Comment: I updated the nvidia drivers and everything works now

Comment: how did you do that? i only recently `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390` ... (btw i was getting exactly the same as you - gnome disappearing was just because I had both cables plugged in and I was seeing screen 2)

Comment: use 410 one. should fix it

Answer (score 0):

To collect the comments in an answer, I did ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-390  # i had this version already installed
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

At the time of writing, this installed 415 and worked beautifully